# Mouseover with three attempts

Tags: javascript, events, hover, mouseover

I have this code:

```
mug.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    if (//I don't know what to put in here..) {
        console.log('game over');
    }
}
```

And I basically want it to say that when the user has hovered three times over an image the game is over.

Thanks!

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed. Please be careful with your tagging, since if you tag the wrong folk, you get the wrong experts. `Java != Javascript;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple to do:

```
var mouseOverCount = 0;
mug.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    if (mouseOverCount >= 2) {
        console.log('game over');
    }
    mouseOverCount++;
});
```

I suggest you to read (or watch) some beginner programming tutorials, so you will understand basic concepts. You can find a lot of them in the internet.